# Should terms & conditions upon registration be captured in the database?

Tags: legal, terms-of-use

Should terms and conditions that user accept upon registration and making reservations on a system being captured in a database?

If yes, what is the proper way to do this (e.g. timestamp + IP (the ip address of the users device) + version number of T & C document)?

If no, what is the proper way to handle this in any other way?

Comment: What "IP" are you referring to?

Comment: @MrWhite I am referring to the IP address of the users device. But in essence that's not what the question is about. The question is about how to store terms & conditions.

Comment: @KevinVugts, I think this is a question better suited for the company attorney.  There's probably case law for this that specifies what is or isn't acceptable.

Comment: @Trebor Okey! Makes completely sense but I thought there might be some "technical aspects" that we can handle ourselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. You have various options:

- Save user consent in the database (`Y`) and the version of your Terms and Conditions (v1, v2).
- Save only user consent in the database (`Y`) and user creation time (`DateTime`) since you know the version of your Terms and Conditions at the time of consent (ie. Last Effective Date of the agreement is 1st January 2019 and the user signed-up on 2nd January).

Why do you want to save the IP address? A user will sign-up with an email address that will be confirmed (confirmation link) and the consent is given during the sign-up process.

[image]

Whenever you update your Terms & Conditions, notify and ask for user consent again.

[image]